# ng-repeater printed result 0; when I run the function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this problem outputting the result of `$scope.getID` to html because the result will show 0 each time run the function and doing the calculation 
just want to ask how to print the right result using angular ng-repeater 
https://jsfiddle.net/1m77eshv/

javascript

```
    debugger;
angular.module("app", [])
    .controller('ctrl', ['$scope',

function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        categories: [{
            "Id": 1,
            name: '1'
        }, {
            "Id": 2,
            name: '2'
        },{
            "Id": 3,
            name: '3'
        },{
            "Id": 4,
            name: '4'
        }]

    }
    $scope.result = 0;
    $scope.getID = function(id){
        id=+2;
        $scope.result =id;
        console.log(parentId)
        return result;
    }
}])
```

html

```
 <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
        <div ng-repeat="category in model.categories"> <span> Category: {{ category.name }} </span>
            <div ng-init="getID(category.Id)">
    {{result}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Any reason you have `result` only being calculated on click? Also, your `ng-repeat` will reference the same `result` for each item in `categories`. Do you want every repeated div to show the same `result`?

Comment: sorry guy I updated the code to use ng-init not ng-click sorry for that typo

Comment: @inorganik this code simulate problem I have in real code  because of that I do just random calculation to see if I can print the result  and I running  repeater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that you have only one 'result' variable, so it will be always the same inside de repeat. If all you want is to see the loop working, here's your code: https://jsfiddle.net/1m77eshv/3/

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="category in model.categories"> <span> Category: {{ category.name }} </span>
     <div>
        {{getID(category.Id)}}
     </div>
</div>
function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        categories: [{
            "Id": 1,
            name: '1'
        }, {
            "Id": 2,
            name: '2'
        },{
            "Id": 3,
            name: '3'
        },{
            "Id": 4,
            name: '4'
        }]

    }

    $scope.getID = function(id){
        return id+=2;

    }
}])
```

Comment: Instead of `{{ results[$index] }}` why not just `{{ getID(category.Id) }}` with his original getID function?

Comment: Just trying to modify the minimum the code on the question, but i can change the example

Comment: Your modification is wrong, you're still just referencing `result`. Take out the interpolation all together and just change `ng-init` to `ng-bind-html`

Comment: @Abdallah.Mohamed look at the example now please